# Create a file/folder per user and automatically dispatch rights

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, active-directory, access-rights

My company decided to distribute some individual PDFs to each employee.

Say, the John Doe, Mark Twain and Anne Moore have some PDFs to get, like
"John Doe.pdf", "Mark Twain.pdf" and "Anne Moore.pdf"

Is there a way to automatically dispatch the pdf to a SharePoint library, give the respective rights, in order that John has access only to John's PDF.

I mean, we suppose that the company has at least several hundreds of people and manually that would take some time.

Answer (score 0):

Per my knowledge, there is no way to do so intelligently, individually identify a document to a specific person and grant access to that specific person.It takes a certain amount of time to operate.

I suggest you custom folders permission for each employee. Create folders that belong to everyone, break inheritance and then just give each individual access.This may be time-consuming at first, but then you can upload files to designated folders so that designated people can only access their own folders.
To change folder permissions, please refer to:https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/change-the-permissions-on-a-subfolder-5427bd7c-f20a-4f75-8cf2-5359dd45a1a6
Thank you for your understanding.

---

If the answer is helpful, please click "√" on the left panel of the answer and kindly upvote it.

Comment: So, if I have 2000 people, I should attribute manually 2000 time the rights, and when it moves next year, once again manually reattribute

Comment: Unfortunately，there is currently no OOTB way to achieve this.

Comment: suppose each file contains the email of the user in first position, could we then user power automate to extract the email, get the user, and attribute rights to the newly created file?

Comment: According to your description, I think it can be realized through Power Automate, extracting the user's mailbox in the file name to identify the user and create a corresponding folder. I suggest you start a new discussion in the Power Automate Community on this issue so that you can get more professional help.